# Google OAuth Developer Verification for iOS email client

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-developers-console

We are a new company developing an email client with the google scope https://mail.google.com/
Our app shows the unverified app screen and we submitted a review request with a youtube video.
We got a reply from the "Api Oauth Dev Verification" we can continue the verification only if we submit the app to the app store.
I wonder if this is an automated type email and we should request a verification before we publish the app or not.

Second question they told me they may require a secutity assessment, I wonder if there is a way to prove that our app is local only and do not send any data to a specified server.

Thank you.